# Validate uniqueness of id pairs in activeadmin nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activeadmin

I'm using Activadmin nested forms, and have this model structure:

**Currency.rb**

```
class Currency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_currencies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :product_currencies
  has_many :variant_currencies
  has_many :variants, through: :variant_currencies

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { minimum: 4 },
                   uniqueness: true
  validates :iso, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 2 },
                  uniqueness: true
end
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :variants
  has_many :product_currencies
  has_many :currencies, through: :product_currencies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_currencies, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  mount_uploader :image, ProductImageUploader

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { minimum: 5 },
                   uniqueness: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true,
                          length: { minimum: 150 }
  validates :short_description, presence: true,
                                length: { in: 15..50 }
  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :subtitle, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

**ProductCurrency.rb**

```
class ProductCurrency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :currency

  validates :currency, presence: true,
                       uniqueness: { scope: :product }
  validates :price, presence: true,
                    numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01 }

end
```

I want the combination of `product_id` and `currecny_id` be unique. The validation of uniqueness in the last model should make the trick, and it does, but only on editing, not on creation, because of using nested forms in Activeadmin (I can add several prices for currency). How can I be sure, the user wouldn't be able to create several prices for one currency? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have enough points to comment, even though this would have been more helpful as a comment.

Your answer probably lies in [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) which helps you add the validations of the associated element. `validates_associated :product_currencies`

However, validates_associated tends to cause some problems in nested_associations since the `product_id` would not be there at the time of creation of the `product_currency` model. That would give you a validation error - `Product Currency - Product must be present`

The solution for that problem is defining `:inverse_of` in your associations. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force way to do this is to place additional checks in the controller:

```
controller do
  def create
    if extra_validation(params)
      create!
    else
      redirect_to({action: :new}, {alert: ...})
    end
  end
end
```